# Can't register TableCell of TableViews created in UIViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I created a TableView in a standard ViewController. The Problem is that I am not able to register a new Cell. It always leads to folllowing error:
*'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CustomCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'*

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var testView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(testView)

        self.testView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellID")

        self.testView.dataSource = self
        self.testView.delegate = self
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = self.item(at: indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = item
    cell.coverView.image = UIImage(named: "Swift")
    return cell
}
```

Using a storyboard won't cause that problem. If i create the Cell and refer a identifier, registration works perfectly. I just don't understand it programmatically

I tried to register cells using other Navigationcontroller: UITableViewController. It just worked because i used :

```
self.tableView.register(Cellstest.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellID")

//and not using the created TableView "testView". 
//Using self.testView.register  leads to the same error
```

In my opionion with the code above I registered cells for the universal tableView in the UITableViewController instead of my created testView: UITableView.

If i am right, how can i just register a new Cell for the specific TableView

If i am wrong, how am I able to access the UITableViewController in my UIViewController.  Because in the first case using UIViewController I cant access
*self.tableView.register* . 
I am just able to register my own TableView 
*self.testView.register*

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use

```
self.testView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

instead of

```
self.testView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
```

Comment: Yes i tried.  I made some mistakes in my post, so I corrected it.  I registered my Costum Cell with the right identifier. I also tried the universal TableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a XIB File then need to Register a `Nib` object in testView in `viewDidLoad()` method.

please replace:-

```
self.testView.register(UINib(nibName: "nib file name", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell identifier")
```

with:-

```
self.testView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
```

Comment: Heyhey, thanks for the answer. But i am not using a XIB File. My Cell is just a UITableView class. If i create that class via storyboard everything works fine.

Comment: ok fine. I answered because you got an error for an identifier of nib or class so I answer it. can you upvote my answer?

Comment: i tried , but i am new and have less than 15 reputation. It is recorded but wont be public.

Comment: I have upvote your question now you can feel free to upvote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found my Problem. I made a mistake in my Cell. The declaration was unclear and therefore I always registered an ampty

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to watch where you placed the registration. In most cases, We place it in the viewDidLoad, but you also need to watch if anything happened that will load data to the table before registering the Cells. Make sure to register those Cells before doing any data load to the tableView.